# wxDC printing a text on screen while typing

Tags: c++, mfc, wxwidgets

I am trying to show a string on the screen while the user still types it. Normally wxDC's DrawText function is used for a string where the contents of the string is already known.

```
void DrawText(const wxString& text, wxCoord x, wxCoord y)
```

As we know, this function takes a wxString and prints on the screen. However, how can I let the user type something on the screen (on a wxWindow, wxFrame ). All and all, I am working nowadays on a drawing program where users can draw certain shapes. Certain shapes are easy to draw, move etc... But having a textbox and letting user type something in it is bugging my mind so far. Of course, this should be editable such as when the user clicks again on the same "text box" I should be able to edit it.

One last point, I am trying to avoid using controls such as wxTextCtrl and in a sense trying to make my own textctrl. What would be the best starting point?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to do anything special here. As long as the user is in some kind of "edit" mode - i.e. you're expecting them to type text - then all you need to do is to redraw everything whenever the user enters more text.

Something like this:

1. User clicks inside a rect to edit text.
2. Program starts edit mode (some internal state initialises an empty string).
3. While user didn't click outside the rect

   - add the entered character to the text string
   - clear the drawing area inside the rect to background
   - call `DrawText` or more likely `DrawLabel` to draw the string in the rect

Then the text is redrawn as it changes and you have a string with the content for persistence if necessary.

Alternatively, you can just pop up a `wxDialog` with a `wxTextCtrl` to ask the user for the whole text string and then draw after the dialog is closed.

Makes sense?

Comment: In that case OnPaint is called when the user enters a text. Would it be efficient to call OnPaint especially when there are other objects?

Also how shall I implement a delete or let the user place a cursor in the middle of the string and start deleting it. I might be totally wrong but maybe wxTextValidator will help in such a case, but I am not sure how I can use it.

Comment: @macroland It shouldn't be inefficient to repaint, that happens frequently anyway, but I'm not so sure about in-place editing - maybe you need to get something basic working first. The way I described would handle initial entry ok and you can cope with backspace etc. It will be difficult to provide click-and-edit in mid string though.

Comment: I checked the code for wxTextCtrl and it seems rather complicated to make a textCtrl (editable, etc...) or similarly a wxGrid control. Maybe I should give up the idea and just show a temporary wTextCtrl and get the text and then delete it when the focus is gone away.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own `wxTextCtrl` is difficult, I'd strongly recommend against doing this. But if you really want to (why?), then it's, of course, possible, after all `wxRichTextCtrl` which has significantly more features than the plain `wxTextCtrl` is written using only wxWidgets API.

And there is no particular magic here, you just need to update the window (ideally, use [wxWindow::RefreshRect()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#ab0ae6b9898cd261c39ebeb2891aa3d67) instead of refreshing the entire window) whenever the text displayed in it changes and your `wxEVT_PAINT` handler must be capable of drawing the text correctly.

Comment: I think wxTextEntry can help to solve lots of problems. HOwever, now I have a basic problem. I can not get the char event routed to the window
SetWindowStyle(wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL|wxWANTS_CHARS );
    Connect( wxEVT_KEY_DOWN, wxKeyEventHandler( DeviceContextFrame::OnKeyDown ) );
    Connect( wxEVT_CHAR, wxKeyEventHandler( DeviceContextFrame::OnChar ) );

dont seem to fire events.

Comment: You can't route events to a native window. You should give it the focus so that it receives the keyboard events on its own. It is much simpler, too.

Comment: Instead of writing my own wxTextCtrl I am temporarily showing the wxTextCtrl and deleting it whenever the user presses somewhere else. I think this is an easier approach